# Can't Log in with Facebook when I export my application

Tags: php, android, facebook

I built an App with the Facebook SDK, everything was working fine on Emulator, but when I exported my app to Run on my mobile device, I couldn't do the log in, its frustrating because this is my first App and I thought that everything was working without errors.

My Login in works as a registering button too. When someone without an account tries to login, it automatically creates an account using the data from Facebook.

I'm using PHP to insert data into my Database, I'm calling this function when someone tries to Log in:

```
case "loginfb":
        facebook_func($_POST['email'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['gender'],$_POST['image']);
```

My function calls a Query to check if the sent E-mail already exists to do the normal login, else, it creates a new account.

```
    function facebook_func($email,$name,$gender,$image){

    $result = db_queries("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row[16] == 1){ //row 16 check if the account uses social network login
        if($row[0]){ //Check if the id exists on database
        echo $row[0];
        online_func($row[3],$row[0]);
    }else{
    //Inserts new account into the Database 
    //echo id from the user
    }
}
```

I'm echoing the Id from the user to save it in a Java session.

Session code:

```
public class NewSession extends Application {

   Session session = new Session();

   public String getUserId() {
      return session.suserid; 
   }
}
```

My Main activity full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText email, password;
    private TextView status;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginButton loginButton;


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusField);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                System.out.println("onSuccess");
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {


                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                    GraphResponse response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Application code
                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                        //System.out.println("Check: " + response.toString());
                        try {
                            String id = object.getString("id");
                            String name = object.getString("name");
                            String image = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=600&height=600";
                            String email = object.getString("email");
                            String gender = object.getString("gender");
                            String getgender = "";

                            if (getgender.equals("male")) {
                                getgender = "2";
                            } else {
                                getgender = "1";
                            }
                            facebookLogin(email, name, getgender, image);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                System.out.println("onError");
                Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    public void login(View view) {
        String getemail = email.getText().toString();
        String getpassword = password.getText().toString();
        new SigninActivity(this, status).execute(getemail, getpassword);
    }

    public void facebookLogin(String email, String name, String gender, String image) {
        new FBSigninActivity(this, status).execute(email, name, gender, image);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "...",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

My facebook login class

```
public class FBSigninActivity extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

    private TextView statusField;
    private Context context;
    private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds

    public FBSigninActivity(Context context, TextView statusField) {
        this.context = context;
        this.statusField = statusField;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...arg0) {

        try {
            String getemail = (String) arg0[0];
            String getname = (String) arg0[1];
            String getgender = (String) arg0[2];
            String getimage = (String) arg0[3];
            String link = "http://www.website.pt/Android/index.php?section=loginfb";
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(getemail, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(getname, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("gender", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(getgender, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("image", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(getimage, "UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(link);


            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "pass".toCharArray());
                }
            });

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result == "") {
            Toast.makeText(context, "shows error",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(context, "welcome message",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String newuser = result.substring(0, 1);
            String newid = result.substring(1);

            if (newuser.equals("N")) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Session.suserid = newid;

                Intent in = new Intent(context,
                editProfile.class);

                in .putExtra("checku", "new");

                context.startActivity( in );

            }else{
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ListUsersActivity.class));
                Session.suserid = result;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: When I try to Login my App crashes

Comment: would you show the logcat??

Comment: I can't, my app only crashes when exported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a release apk, it's signed with a different keystore, so the first key hash that you created and put into the Facebook app settings won't work for the release apk.

You need to get another key hash, for the new apk, and also add that to your settings as well.